# <input> height on Mac

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, safari

The following code:

`<input style="height: 80px; width: 200px;" value="test button">`

Works fine on Windows, Linux etc. However Mac uses the system button style for `<input>` tags. These seem to not be able to be given a custom height (Firefox overrides the system button style so it's fine but Chrome and Safari on Mac have the below problem):

Instead of having a 80px wide and 200px high button there is the Mac button style and a gap on top and below. The width gets set fine.

How do I override this so that Chrome and Safari on Mac show a tall button?

EDIT: Here's what happens on Mac:
[image: Mac input{ height: 200px; } problem]
Here's what should happen (works on Windows, Linux):
[image: Normal input{ height: 200px; }]

Comment: It's working fine on my MBP with Chrome or Safari

Comment: Does this work? http://www.duncannz.com/pages/stutter-count.php?mobile=1 Thanks

Comment: BTW it seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682520/css-how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-osx-submit-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add :

```
input[type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

in your CSS :-)

[Here](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance) is the list of all values this property can take. By default, WebKit uses a custom style (with fixed height) for the buttons.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use a `<button>`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Seems stupid we need proprietary styles for a button, but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try after adding type="button"

```
<input style="height: 80px; width: 200px;" value="test button" type="button">
```

Comment: It's already in his code even if it didn't write it down in the post

Comment: Sorry didn't post full tag. I already was using type="button"

Comment: I followed the link he gave in the comment. And I was not or did not want to seem aggresive