# Height not being applied to search box without border

Tags: html, css, macos

I have an input of type search that I am trying to resize the height of.  The height is never actually reflected unless I apply a border to the element.  I have tried using line-height, font-size, min-height,max-height, and the height attribute on the element itself, nothing seems to work.  Is there any way to resize the search box without applying a border?

```css
#search{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:10px auto 0;
 height:50px;
}
#searchborder{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:10px auto 0;
 height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="search">
<input id="searchborder" type="search">
```

**Update**
So after checking on a Windows Machine it seems like the search input is rendering properly, for reference here is what I'm seeing on my Mac.  [image: screenshot from my mac]

Any way to make this render properly on OSX?

Comment: Both search boxes in your Snippet reflect the height style using Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question the height is applied either way but you just don't see the edges, lets say you applied a background, border or no border the applied height would be visible

Comment: I think it's an issue with OSX.  On my computer the first searchbox looks to only be 15 or 20 pixels tall.  I just pulled up this page on my coworker's win7 machine and it looks fine.  I checked in chrome, firefox, and safari on my mac.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009113/input-height-on-mac for a similar question and possible solution.

Comment: have you tried `-webkit-appearance: none;`?

Comment: Just tried that, and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the time these two CSS/HTML snippets alone function the exact same and have height applied. The only difference is you can see the border on the #searchborder input.

However, search inputs can be rendered differently in different OS and Browsers. Webkit can be tricky with OSX. See the following article about styling CSS search inputs:

https://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/

A suggestion at the bottom of that page would be to remove the webkit appearance by adding a CSS line and then the height will be applied:

```
#search{
-webkit-appearance: none;
display:block;
width:90%;
margin:10px auto 0;
height:50px;}
```