# Why the Roboto Mono font is not applied on an input of type submit, when using Chrome or Safari?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am building a very simple web page in which I am using the `Roboto Mono` font family from Google Fonts repository.

I have overridden the user agent fonts for the form and it works for the input of type `text`. But it does not seem to be working for the input of type `submit`.

The HTML code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,700,500italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Font Example in Forms</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS code is this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* This is to override the user agent styles */

input,
textarea,
select,
keygen,
button {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.2rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

You can see that live here:

```
http://jsbin.com/foqiso/edit?html,css,output
```

Any clue why the font of the button is not 'Roboto Mono' ?

**Update** I forgot to tell you that I am loading this page on Chrome. It seems that when I am loading the page on Firefox, everything works as expected. Same problem appears on Safari too. My OS is MAC OS X Yosemite.

**Update about duplicate question**: My question has been flagged as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664610/cant-style-text-on-input-submit-button-as-bold). It is true that they both try to apply a style on an input of type `submit` and style is not applied on Chrome. But, the answer on that question, although it gives a workaround (add a background color) it does not explain why this problem occurs on Chrome and Safari? Is it a bug on those browsers?

Comment: The button font is Roboto Mono in your example.

Comment: Seems like it's working: http://i.imgur.com/pRLFgPU.png

Comment: @Dorian which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @herrh which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit), Windows 10.

Comment: @herrh Hmmm. I believe that the problem occurs on Mac.

Comment: did you try `<button type="submit">text</button>` as a workaround?

Comment: @herrh You are right. This is a workaround that works. Also, I have found another less acceptable workaround. To add a `background-color` to the particular `input` of type `submit`. This, magically, solves the problem. But the question is why?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos This is a native button style. Found another workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682520/css-how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-osx-submit-button) `-webkit-appearance: button;`

Comment: @herhh Yes. that is the correct workaround. You can add that as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos OS X El Captain and Chrome 47